# How can I use a transactional database to create a critical section?

Tags: database, oracle, critical-section

Say I have 2 servers that talk to the same transactional database.

I want to set it up such that only one of these two servers will perform a given timed action (essentially using the database to enforce synchronization). From what I've heard, something along the lines of this might work:

Say my table TABLE has 2 columns, ID and STATUS. If I set up the code as such:

```
update TABLE set STATUS = 'processing' where ID = 1234 and STATUS != 'processing'

if (weHaveModifiedAtLeastOneRow)
{
    // do critical section stuff here
    // This is code that we only want one server to run, not both.

    update TABLE set STATUS = 'free' where ID = 1234
}
else
{
    // We failed to get the lock, so do nothing
}
```

Will this work, or am I missing some concepts here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a critical section, use [dbms_lock.request](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i1002556). You could get a meaningful lock handle trough allocate unique like this:

```
DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE ( lockname =>  'MYAPP_' || ID, lockhandle => handle);
success := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST(lockhandle => handle, timeout => 1);
if (success = 0) then
-- Do stuff
DBMS_LOCK.release(handle);
else
-- we waited a second and didn't got the lock.
end if;
```

if you prefer it, you could apply a hash and the modulo operator over id, to project the id value space over a known number of locks, accepting a (low)risk of delaying unrelated transactions.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of rolling our own locks; however, this is a case where it might be a solution.  However, we still need to ensure that both calling servers use the same ID when issuing the lock, so it seems like we're just transferring the synchronization problem rather than solving it.